# Why isn't Coldbox route-visualizer displaying in browser after successful install?

Tags: coldfusion, coldbox

I have Coldbox and a Coldbox app on my local machine, which I'm using for a Coldbox hands-on video course (CFcasts.com, "Coldbox from Zero to Hero Workshop). I just successfully installed the route-visualizer module for Coldbox via Commandbox:

```
install route-visualizer --savedev
```

And CommandBox says it was installed. Then I did a reinit:

```
coldbox reinit
```

And my server reinitted. Ortus documentation says I should now be able to go to 127.0.0.1:42518/route-visualizer and see something in my browser, but instead I'm getting an error message from Coldbox: "The event: route-visualizer is not a valid registered event." I've tried repeating the steps above, with the same results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is the `route-visualizer` module installed in the `/modules` folder of your working site?  Once in awhile I will run the `install` command from the wrong directory and then wonder where my module is. :)

It's also possible that the reinit command isn't hitting the right server.

I would suggest a manual reinit ( `http://127.0.0.1:42518?fwreinit=1` ).

Comment: No, the only folder I see in /modules is "cfmigrations". So a folder for route-visualizer should necessarily appear in /modules after I run the install command? I'm definitely running the install command from my app's root directory. Nothing different after a manual reinit.

Comment: BUT...I do see a folder for route-visualizer in a folder called "-savedev". Since this is just a dummy app I'm building as part of a video course, I'll try installing without the "--savedev" added...Yup. Now it's working. Not sure why it wasn't working before. Just to be 100% certain, the correct syntax for the command is "install route-visualizer --saveDev", correct?

Comment: I must have just mistyped with the first install. I just uninstalled, then installed again with the exact command above, which includes the --saveDev, and now it's working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I must have just mistyped with the first install command. I just uninstalled, then installed again with the exact command `install route-visualizer --saveDev`, and now it's working as expected, with the route-visualizer displaying at 127.0.0.1:42518/route-visualizer as expected, and with the `route-visualizer` folder appearing under `/modules`, as expected rather than under `/-saveDev`.